# What type of variable Declaration is this in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift, and have been trying to find the definition for this type of instantiation, but have had no luck. I saw something similar in an example project. What is this called?

Example:

```
var str = "Hello World"

var test: Int {
    var testVal = 5

    if !str.isEmpty {
       testVal = 10
    }
    return testVal
}
```

In XCode playground, this will show the value for `str` but not for `test`. Not until you type `test` on a new line, or use it elsewhere. I thought it was an example of an [`autoclosure`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), but that has a more deliberate syntax, and immediately runs.

Example of autoclosure with shortcut syntax:

```
var str = "Hello World"

var test: Int = {
    var testVal = 5

    if !str.isEmpty {
       testVal = 10
    }
    return testVal
}()
```

This latter example will define `test` right away, and you'll see the output in playground, for instance. The advantage of the former is that, for more complex situations, it will delay defining the value

Comment: There is even a third form to add `lazy`  before `var test` in the second example.The difference is that the initialization will not be preformed until the variable is accessed the first time - like a computed property but the code is run once.

Comment: Yeah, there are some subtle nuances in these types that don't have equivalents in my other languages (enforced at the language-level, at least). As @atreat mentioned, you can only add `lazy` to the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example is a '[Computed Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)', every time that variable is accessed the closure is run. This is how you can override the getter and setters of a property. In your code above, having a single closure implicitly defines that as the getter. You could also do:

```
var test: Int {
  get {
    var testVal = 5

    if !str.isEmpty {
      testVal = 10
    }
    return testVal
  }
  set(value) {
    test = value
  } 
}
```

Your second example is simply defining a closure that is executed immediately. This closure will only be run once when the object is initialized. It is useful to follow this pattern when you want to have computed properties that are 'lazy'. When lazy, the closure would be run once when the property is first accessed, not when the object is initialized.

The syntax looks very similar, but the ideas of computer properties and lazy properties have subtle differences. It is important to note that computer properties can not be marked as `lazy`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, so thanks! I ran across the other parts of computed properties, but didn't see this shortcut get{} declaration syntax.

Comment: There's also a shorthand for the `set` to. The full declaration would be `set (value: Int)`, but you can shorten it to `set (value)` (to use type inference, this is what @atreat posted), and then even more to just `set` (in which case the default name `newValue` is implied)

Comment: It might be nice for newcomers to see a breakdown of the various shortcuts compared to the full example in its most verbose form. Not sure if that exists in any tutorial tho...

Answer (score 1):

It's a **Computed Property**.

Computed properties defer to *stored properties* in the way you assign a value to the property (or variable) itself. In your case the `str` variable is a stored property since you're assigning a value without further operations on the value itself.

If you examine the `test` variable you notice that to assign a value you need to perform further operations and then *return* the actual piece of information you want to store. Computed properties can also return the value of a stored property as well and they provide a getter and an optional setter to themselves.